# Change Toolbar & AppBarLayout Background onCreate

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to have 2 theme options for my app, Dark and Light. When the dark theme is selected I use sharedpreference to save and apply the theme on startup. But when I try to change the background color of the toolbar & appBarLayout like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long currentTheme = sharedPref.getInt(getString(string.current_theme), 0);
    if (currentTheme == 0) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
    }
    if (currentTheme == 1) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Dark);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(ActionbarDark));
    }
```

Logcat returns the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference`

And I cant understand why

Update: Fixed it by using the answer from @Nilesh Rathod and changing the theme of the activity before setting the content view, then after setting content view changing the theme of the Toolbar and AppBarLayout.

Comment: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); You have missed R here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed R in `findViewById` of toolbar

**it should like below**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

**change your code like this**

```
Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long currentTheme = sharedPref.getInt(getString(string.current_theme), 0);
    if (currentTheme == 0) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);

    }
    if (currentTheme == 1) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Dark);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentmanager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new FirstFragment())
            .commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, string.navigation_drawer_open, string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Still returns `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @DanielArena add yur xml file with question

Comment: @DanielArena what is ActionbarDark

Comment: try this         toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ActionbarDark); @DanielArena

Comment: toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ActionbarDark));
 
Still returns error

Comment: @DanielArena can your share your oncreate method and where you did setcontent view

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: The new error is with context how would I define it for MainActivity

Comment: MainActivity.this like this

Comment: The error is back to `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference`

After defining context correctly

Comment: share your color.xml and your oncreate method

Comment: @check updted ans

Comment: Cant find symbol toolbar in this line `this, drawer, toolbar, string.navigation_drawer_open, string.navigation_drawer_close);`

Since it was removed

Comment: With your code and the toolbar defined correctly I get this : 
 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference`

Comment: check updtaed ans

Comment: It still returns java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: plase share your app theme adn style.xml also

Comment: I googled the error and fixed my code but It breaks the theme background (check updated question) It makes it white and therefore text is invisible, do you know why this would happen?

Comment: didn't get your problem can your share pic for that

Comment: I've fixed all the issues, I needed to change the Activity theme before setting content view and change toolbar theme afterwards. Thanks for your help